# get public ip of instances in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I am trying to get the public ip address of all the running instances.
I am using boto3 and python version 2.7.6.

```
>>> instances = ec2.instances.filter(
    ...     Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])
>>> for instance in instances:
...     print(instance.public_ip_address,instance.platform,instance.public_dns_name);
```

It lists all the instances along with instances not having public ip address assigned to it.

```
(None, None, '')
```

Is there any way to filter out those instances which do not have a public ip while populating instances using ec2.instances.filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filter(lambda x:x[0] is not None, instances)
```

Comment: Is there any way to filter out ip's when getting the list of instances using ec2.instances.filter ?

Comment: @user3351750 What's wrong with `instances = filter(lambda x:x[0] is not None, ec2.instances.filter( ... Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}]))`?

Comment: I used     `result = filter(lambda x:x.public_ip_address is not None,instances);`  I am just curious to know whether is it possible in `ec2.instances.filter ` method. I am new to both python and boto

Comment: @user3351750 You can't modify methods like that. If you want to do that you must rewrite that method with a custom filter by looking at that method's source. Also if my answer is correct, accept it.